# Helmholtz Free Energy and Equation of State for particles in a box

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, partition-function

> The energy levels for a particle in a box of length $L $ are $\epsilon_n = \frac{\hbar n \pi \nu}{L} $ where $n $ is a positive integer and $\nu $ has dimensions of velocity.
>
> a) Find the Helmholtz free energy $F$ of a system of $N$ identical, non-interacting particles of this sort in a box of size $L$ in thermal contact with a reservoir at temperature $\tau$. **Keep only extensive quantities.**
>
> b) Find the equation of state relating $\tau, p, L$.

**a)** The partition function of one particle is:
$$Z_1 = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \exp(-\frac{\hbar n \pi \nu}{L \tau}) = \frac {1}{\exp(\frac{\hbar \pi \nu}{L \tau}) - 1}$$
and the partition function for $N $ identical non-interacting particles is:
$$Z_N = \frac {Z_1^N}{N!}$$
The Hemholtz Free energy is
$$F = -\tau \log(Z_n) = -N\tau \log(Z_1) + \tau \log(N!)$$
Assuming $N >> 1$ (this assumption is not made in the problem, but seems reasonable enough to me), $\log(N!) \approx N \log(N) - N$

$$F \approx N \tau \log( \exp(\frac{\hbar \pi \nu}{L \tau}) - 1) + N \tau \log(N) - N \tau$$

I'm not sure what terms I should be keeping here. I'd be tempted to keep only $N \tau$, as I don't see immediately why any of the quantities involving logarithm would be extensive. However, I know that entropy is extensive, which involved logarithms, and moreover, dropping the logarithmic terms here would be dropping the largest (and most relevant) contributions to the free energy, so I'm doubtful that is the case.

**b)** I believe I can do this substituting in $V^{1/3} = L$ and then exploiting the relation:
$$p = -(\frac{\partial F}{\partial V})|_{\tau}$$
And then substituting $L^3 = V$ back in after taking this derivative. Would this be the correct approach (of course, once I have the issues settled with $F$)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that cryptic "keep only extensive quantities" might mean make the approximation $ \exp(\frac{\hbar \pi \nu}{L \tau}) - 1=\frac{\hbar \pi \nu}{L \tau}$. Then you get intensive $N/L$ in your logarithm.

For your second part I think you are on the right track. But I suspect they are considering this a one dimensional system where the pressure is conjugate to $L$ not $L^3$. So then $p = -(\frac{\partial F}{\partial L})|_{\tau}$.

Comment: You make good points, thank you! Just to make sure I follow (extensive and intensive analysis always gives me trouble), after making that approximation for the exponential term (and the dropping it due to intensivity), I'd just be left with:
$F \approx N \tau \log(N) - N \tau$

Comment: No you leave it in there. The only thing you drop are the higher order terms in the exponential expansion. The idea behind F being extensive is if you replace N by 2N and L by 2L you should get 2F. If you have quantities like $N/L$ that is okay, in fact you need that L there to cancel extensivity of the N in the logarithm.

Comment: Ahhh, yes, I see what you're saying! Thanks for the help!